# jQuery hide a TR that has matching text or data attributes

Tags: jquery

I'd like create a filter that acts on all columns in a table, in particular, ignoring the formatting of telephone numbers.

I thought the easiest approach to this was to add the numeric parts of the telephone number to the nearest `TD` as a data attribute.

The text-search functionality works as expected, but I can't seem to get the data-attribute search to work.

What am I missing?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#inputSearch").on("keyup", function() {

    // search string
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    // filter
    $("#tableContacts tr").filter(function() {

      // search text (functions correctly)
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      // search work-telephone attributes; does not work; disabled
      // || $(this).children('td').data('work-telephone').value.indexOf(value) > -1
      // search mobile-telephone attributes; does not work; disabled
      // || $(this).children('td').data('mobile-telephone').value.indexOf(value) > -1

    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search..." autofocus><br/>
<table id="tableContacts" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>domain</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th>work</th>
      <th>mobile</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/contacts/5">Morticia Addams</a></td>
      <td>ghouhl.io</td>
      <td><a href="mailto:Morticia.Addams@ghouhl.io" class="text-truncate">Morticia.Addams@ghouhl.io</a></td>
      <td data-work-telephone="88855512342"><a href="tel:(888) 555-1234 x2">(888) 555-1234 x2</a></td>
      <td data-mobile-telephone="8885552222"><a href="tel:(888) 555-2222">(888) 555-2222</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/contacts/6">Gomez Addams</a></td>
      <td>ghouhl.io</td>
      <td><a href="mailto:Gomez.Addams@ghouhl.io" class="text-truncate">Morticia.Addams@ghouhl.io</a></td>
      <td data-work-telephone="88855512341"><a href="tel:(888) 555-1234 x1">(888) 555-1234 x1</a></td>
      <td data-mobile-telephone="8885553333"><a href="tel:(888) 555-3333">(888) 555-3333</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I fixed your HTML (missing tr, extra <i> ) and created a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `.data('propety-name')` return the actual contents of the attribute so the `.value` you add is wrong, returning `undefined`.
2. Also `$(this).children('td')` will return all the `<td>` but the `data` will only work on the first `<td>` in that list.
3. Then you need to target `<tr>` inside the `<tbody>` to avoid affecting the ones in the `<thead>`
4. Finally, you  need to actually `return` the value for the `.filter` function to work (*unless you do not need to actually filter in which case you should use `each` instead*)

So, assuming there is only one `data-work-telephone` and one `data-mobile-telephone` per `<tr>` you should do

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#inputSearch").on("keyup", function() {

    // search string
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    // filter

    $("#tableContacts tbody tr").each(function() {

      var self = $(this),
        td = self.children(),
        text = self.text().toLowerCase(),
        workPhone = (td.filter('[data-work-telephone]').data('work-telephone') || '').toString(),
        mobilePhone = (td.filter('[data-mobile-telephone]').data('mobile-telephone') || '').toString(),
        match = text.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
        workPhone.indexOf(value) > -1 ||
        mobilePhone.indexOf(value) > -1;

      self.toggle(match)
    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search..." autofocus><br/>
<table id="tableContacts" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>domain</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th>work</th>
      <th>mobile</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/contacts/5">Morticia Addams</a></td>
      <td>ghouhl.io</td>
      <td><a href="mailto:Morticia.Addams@ghouhl.io" class="text-truncate">Morticia.Addams@ghouhl.io</a></td>
      <td data-work-telephone="88855512342"><a href="tel:(888) 555-1234 x2">(888) 555-1234 x2</a></td>
      <td data-mobile-telephone="8885552222"><a href="tel:(888) 555-2222">(888) 555-2222</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/contacts/6">Someone else</a></td>
      <td>domain.tld</td>
      <td><a href="mailto:Someone.else@domain.tld" class="text-truncate">Someone.else@domain.tld</a></td>
      <td data-work-telephone="1321321546"><a href="tel:(132) 132-1546">(888) 555-1234</a></td>
      <td>N/A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For numeric values `data(key)` will return a number not string